# Distinguishing Bound from Unbound Variables

Tags: variables, macros, common-lisp

I'm trying to write a macro, called `different`, to test whether two user-provided arguments are provisionally `eq`, where the arguments may be bound or unbound. But I'm getting lost in the possibilities (and perhaps logic). The following seems to work, but needs enhancement (including avoiding variable capture and multiple evaluation):

```
(defmacro different (item1 item2)
  `(not (eq (if (boundp ',item1) ,item1 ',item1)
            (if (boundp ',item2) ,item2 ',item2))))
```

The basic idea is to look for any unbound variable, quote it, and then see if that is `eq` to the value of the other variable. (The goal is to save the end-user from having to decide when to quote arguments, since bound variables are otherwise marked.)

So now:

```
if x is unbound and y is bound to 'x, or
   y is unbound and x is bound to 'y
(different x y) => NIL 

if x is unbound and y is bound to 'z, or
   y is unbound and x is bound to 'z
(different x y) => T
```

The main problem is that item1 or item2 can be designators for arbitrary lisp objects (in which case `equalp` would be substituted for `eq`). For example:

```
(defparameter x 3)
(different x 3) => NIL (since they are equalp)

(defparameter x '(a b c))
(different x (c b a)) => T  (where (c b a) gets quoted)
```

Can this be factored into the macro, and can the if statements be brought outside the backquote?

Comment: Note that BOUNDP only works for special variables - not for lexical variables.

Comment: What's the relationship between EQ and EQUALP? EQ compares object identity. EQUALP compares some objects of the same type by value, some by contents and some by EQ...

Comment: I think that if you get something like this to run, you will have created mostly a way to confuse anyone touching the code using it.  I mean, Perl is confusing enough, and it just converts between numbers and strings whenever it feels like it.  You now want to convert between symbols and the values of variables named by them, depending on some implicit global state.  Just saying.

Comment: @Svante. Point taken. But it's all confined to one macro. The bigger problem I now see (per Rainer Joswig above) is that the bound variables are always lexical, so boundp won't work. It still seems like a worthwhile/simplifying user interface to me, but I can explore other alternatives (or just require lisp code instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only six cases to deal with

Here is a mapping of what is to be done:

```
For b ≡ bound symbol
For u ≡ unbound symbol
For e ≡ any other value
b b -> eq
b u -> equalp
u u -> equalp
e e -> equalp
e u -> ERROR (makes no sense)
e b -> equalp
```

Hopefully this helps you organize your branching logic. I like to pull some paper and work through branching when I get an explosion like this. Normally it is possible to reduce it using predicate calculus, or come up with another representation that has less branches.

Comment: Thanks for analyzing Spenser. After looking over your listing, it seems like it might be simplified even further. (But would appreciate knowing if this is misunderstanding some basic lisp concepts.) Maybe the arguments passed into the macro could be divided into bound symbols (otherwise called variables), and everything else, which are arbitrary lisp objects (nonvariables). The nonvariables then can be divided into those that evaluate to themselves (numbers, characters, vectors, functions, hash-tables, etc), and those that don't (eg, x, 'x, (a b c), '(a b c), etc).

Comment: So if evaluating a macro argument produces an error, then it is a nonvariable. If it evaluates to itself, then it is also a nonvariable. But if it evaluates to something other than itself, it is a bound variable. Does this make sense and worth trying to code?